# Error too many connectons after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Recentlly i created a app on laravel 5.4, and than i deployed has i normally do, the only difference is that i made a app with version 5.4.
But something get wrong, after i login and got redirect to the admin dashboard im getting a error of "Error of too many connections", i cant figure out what i made wrong? Is completelly normal has i always do.

Note: this error is only hapenning online, in my localhost machine works fine.

Here is my routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('admin/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('admin/', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::post('admin/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');


/************** ADMIN AREA ********************/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {

Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard');

//Surveys
Route::get('admin/surveys/', 'SurveyController@index');
Route::get('admin/surveys/create', 'SurveyController@create');
Route::post('admin/surveys', 'SurveyController@store');
Route::get('admin/surveys/{id}/edit', 'SurveyController@edit');
Route::put('admin/surveys/{id}', 'SurveyController@update');
Route::delete('admin/surveys/{id}', 'SurveyController@destroy');

Route::get('admin/surveys/{id}/{email}/show', 'SurveyController@show');
Route::get('admin/surveys/{id}/results', 'SurveyController@results');

//Questions
Route::get('admin/questions/', 'QuestionController@index');
Route::get('admin/questions/create', 'QuestionController@create');
Route::post('admin/questions', 'QuestionController@store');
Route::get('admin/questions/{id}/edit', 'QuestionController@edit');
Route::put('admin/questions/{id}', 'QuestionController@update');
Route::delete('admin/questions/{id}', 'QuestionController@destroy');

//Answers
Route::post('admin/answers', 'AnswerController@store');
Route::get('admin/answers', 'AnswerController@index');

//Statistics
Route::get('admin/statistics','StatisticController@index');

//Questions Options
Route::get('admin/optionsquestions/', 'QuestionOptionController@index');
Route::get('admin/optionsquestions/create', 'QuestionOptionController@create');
Route::post('admin/optionsquestions', 'QuestionOptionController@store');
Route::get('admin/optionsquestions/{id}/edit', 'QuestionOptionController@edit');
Route::put('admin/optionsquestions/{id}', 'QuestionOptionController@update');
Route::delete('admin/optionsquestions/{id}', 'QuestionOptionController@destroy');

// Settings
Route::get('admin/settings', 'SettingController@edit');
Route::put('admin/settings/update', 'SettingController@update');




});


//Survey Online
Route::get('surveys/{id}/show', 'SurveyController@showPublic');
```

After some more tests i notice that the issue was in my admin middleware, when i remove it, it already worked, i leave above my middleware, can someone figure out what is wrong with it?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->account_type_id == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

Comment: It seems you're using mysql and the user is already being used or something like that, check the log file in storage/logs for more track info please

Comment: Error with your host system. That's why it only happens in production. I bet you are on shared hosting. Perhaps with limited resources.

Comment: Yes,im on a shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

Too many redirect error means you have used middleware for login system and middleware continue redirect from one route to another continusoly and so browser throw too many redirection error.
you need to remove middleware from any one route so it remove too many redirection error.

Comment: But what is wrong with my routes, it looks normal, i believe that how it woks middleware.

Comment: It looks like the problem was here:
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], ...After i remove 'admin'. it already works, but why?

Comment: in login logout system you use middleware. and you put that middleware in some of route group. now if you access to any route within your route group it go in middleware and check validation.

Comment: in your case you might placed  middleware validation fail route in your route group..

Comment: i think you have problem with your admin middleware.

Comment: try to change if portion code to else or visa versa. then see.

Comment: Found the issue, the problem was that in my user table i didnt set the account_type_id to the user, so when the Admin middleware tryied to check if the user was the admin, by checking the account_type_id it starts failing.